# How to use string to pass value instead of choosing from tree node in c#

Tags: c#, treeview, categories

I have a tree created by:

```
//Create and populate an instance of category tree
        int catId = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["processesCategoryId"]);
        Category cat = new Category(catId);
        CategoryUITree.categorySet2UITree(cat.name,
            PSProcesses, this.categoryTreeView, true, false);
```

When user choose a node, it will detect by :

```
CategorySet processes = CategoryUITree.UITree2CategorySet(this.categoryTreeView, false);
```

So if I choose a node named "Design", using debug I can see processes's value is `{Design}`.
Now, I want to pass directly the value "Design" to process, from string variable, no need to choose from the tree.
I tried:

```
CategorySet processes = "Design"
```

but it shows error about wrong type.
Is there anyway I can use string value to form CategorySet processes ?
The CategorySet is defined by:

```
public class CategorySet : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    protected ArrayList _categorySet;
    protected int _setId;

    public CategorySet();
    public CategorySet(int id);

    public int Count { get; }
    public int id { get; }
    public bool IsFixedSize { get; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    public bool IsSynchronized { get; }
    public object SyncRoot { get; }

    public Category this[int index] { get; }

    public int Add(Category categoryToAdd);
    public void Add(CategorySet catSet);
    public void Add(int categoryID);
    public void Add(string phraseSet);
    public void Clear();
    protected void constructFromReader(IDataReader rdr);
    public bool Contains(Category categoryToFind);
    public bool Contains(int catId);
    public void CopyTo(Category[] array, int index);
    public void Delete();
    public void Delete(SqlTransaction transaction);
    public object GetAt(int index);
    public string GetCategoryList();
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    public int IndexOf(Category categoryToFind);
    public void Insert(int index, Category categoryToInsert);
    public CategorySet Intersect(CategorySet withThis);
    public void Remove(Category categoryToRemove);
    public void Remove(int id);
    public void Remove(string name);
    public void RemoveAll();
    public void RemoveAt(int index);
    public void Save();
    public void Save(SqlTransaction transaction);
    public CategorySet Subtract(CategorySet set2);
    public string ToIdString(string separator);
    public string ToNameString(string separator);
    public override string ToString();
    public CategorySet Union(CategorySet withThis);

    protected class SortCategoryById : IComparer
    {
        public SortCategoryById();
    }

    protected class SortCategoryByName : IComparer
    {
        public SortCategoryByName();
    }
}
```

Comment: you may not directly assign/convert a string value to CategorySet

Comment: Yes, how to convert it indirectly, I also wondering...

Comment: it is not directly possible, possibly you can create a constructor with a string parameter in CategorySet class and use the same eg `CategorySet processes = new CategorySet("Design");`

Comment: create a constructor could be a too heavy work? I see here have categorySet2UITree, UITree2CategorySet, cat.name etc. Can I use some of the available definitions here for that purpose ?

Comment: I am not sure about the implementation on the same. so far they look like helper methods to me. you may create a new method named String2CategorySet and write the logic of conversion there.

Comment: I want to do it too but I met difficulty filling in all the fields equivalent to CategorySet. I don't know how they get the value like treenode, parentId, etc. how is it possible doing that with only string value ?